# Add email to URL as parameter - security issue? Javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I've the following issue and would require a second opinion.

A user signs up via a form for a digital service (several input fields). Only one field can be filled out later, but it is required within several days (fieldName: apple).

I'd like to make it as easy as possible for the user to submit this information. Therefore he gets a reminder email after several days with a link to a form "getApple", where he can put the value for "apple" in.

I need to identify this user with a userID, in this case the email address. Is there a way to attach the user email address as a parameter in the URL to prefill my form "getApple"?

Comment: Yes there is. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Luca: yes, of course. I update the question with my recent approach. Since I control the signup process. I set a variable in the localeStorage and if the user clicks the email to get to the form "getApple". I read the localeStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create the link with one of the query parameters to be something like `?email=myemail@example.com` **Make sure you *at least* URL encode the email** so it doesn't break anything.

Then javascript can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript) to pull the value out, deserialize it, and place it into a form field (hidden if you don't want them changing it, visible if it's okay if they change it). When they submit, viola! the email comes across as well.

**Things to consider from a security perspective!** Make sure you sanitize the value passed through the URL, this is an avenue for XSS attacks so make sure you cover yourself on that front. And as always, resanitize all the values on the server to avoid SQL injection and all the other nasties hackers may try. While you can use this method for passing email address or other innocuous information, **DO NOT** use this method to pass log in credentials or other authenticating information.

If you're really paranoid about keeping your users activity secret and safe from any spying (since their email would be recoverable to anyone who can see the url, i.e. listeners, accidental url forwards, etc.) you can encrypt their email with a secret kept on the server to pass through the URL like above, then the form would send the encrypted email, and the server would decrypt with its secret. This is probably unnecessary for most applications.

Comment: thank you, especially for explaining, my approach would be localeStorage since it would be just the email address. I will give it a try and keep you updated.

Comment: Keep in mind localStorage can be deleted by a user. (Or lost if the user moves from one device to another, or just one browser to another).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to encode an email address and send it in the link. And then decode the same method on your server.

ps. For example try use md5.

Comment: There is no way to decrypt MD5. Well, there is, but no _reasonable_ way to do it. That's kind of the point.

Comment: Yes, but you can encode email and save in database. 
Then compare the encoded email in the link with that in the database.

Comment: @paciek that is unnecessary, just encode with a function that can be decoded as well.

Comment: @Kallmanation That's right, that's why I think it's a good way. 
You can also send only the id from the database in the address and check the assigned e-mail to it.

Comment: @paciek, that is overly complicated and adds no value to just using a URL encode-decode. It means the front end has no easy way to see what user this is. It means the user can't make corrections to their email. It means storing more information on the database that is ultimately redundant. It doesn't add any security since MD5 is known to be crackable. Really MD5 is totally unnecessary in this situation.